# How can i use LockBits with a Bitmap to scan for white pixels and then write to a new bitmap all the non white pixels?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is what i did in form1 constructor:

```
Bitmap bmp2 = new Bitmap(@"e:\result1001.jpg");
CropImageWhiteAreas.ImageTrim(bmp2);
bmp2.Save(@"e:\result1002.jpg");
bmp2.Dispose();
```

The class CropImageWhiteAreas:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Test
{
    class CropImageWhiteAreas
    {

        public static Bitmap ImageTrim(Bitmap img)
        {
            //get image data
            BitmapData bd = img.LockBits(new Rectangle(Point.Empty, img.Size),
            ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            int[] rgbValues = new int[img.Height * img.Width];
            Marshal.Copy(bd.Scan0, rgbValues, 0, rgbValues.Length);
            img.UnlockBits(bd);


            #region determine bounds
            int left = bd.Width;
            int top = bd.Height;
            int right = 0;
            int bottom = 0;

            //determine top
            for (int i = 0; i < rgbValues.Length; i++)
            {
                int color = rgbValues[i] & 0xffffff;
                if (color != 0xffffff)
                {
                    int r = i / bd.Width;
                    int c = i % bd.Width;

                    if (left > c)
                    {
                        left = c;
                    }
                    if (right < c)
                    {
                        right = c;
                    }
                    bottom = r;
                    top = r;
                    break;
                }
            }

            //determine bottom
            for (int i = rgbValues.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                int color = rgbValues[i] & 0xffffff;
                if (color != 0xffffff)
                {
                    int r = i / bd.Width;
                    int c = i % bd.Width;

                    if (left > c)
                    {
                        left = c;
                    }
                    if (right < c)
                    {
                        right = c;
                    }
                    bottom = r;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (bottom > top)
            {
                for (int r = top + 1; r < bottom; r++)
                {
                    //determine left
                    for (int c = 0; c < left; c++)
                    {
                        int color = rgbValues[r * bd.Width + c] & 0xffffff;
                        if (color != 0xffffff)
                        {
                            if (left > c)
                            {
                                left = c;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    //determine right
                    for (int c = bd.Width - 1; c > right; c--)
                    {
                        int color = rgbValues[r * bd.Width + c] & 0xffffff;
                        if (color != 0xffffff)
                        {
                            if (right < c)
                            {
                                right = c;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            int width = right - left + 1;
            int height = bottom - top + 1;
            #endregion

            //copy image data
            int[] imgData = new int[width * height];
            for (int r = top; r <= bottom; r++)
            {
                Array.Copy(rgbValues, r * bd.Width + left, imgData, (r - top) * width, width);
            }

            //create new image
            Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            BitmapData nbd
                = newImage.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height),
                    ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            Marshal.Copy(imgData, 0, nbd.Scan0, imgData.Length);
            newImage.UnlockBits(nbd);

            return newImage;
        }

    }
}
```

I also tried before it Peter solution.
In both the result is(This is a screenshot of my facebook after uploaded the image) still the white areas around:

[image: Facebook Screenshot]

You can the rectangle around the image i just uploaded and see what i mean by white area around.

Comment: Just store the result of `GetPixel(x, y)` in a variable, and use that value when calling `SetPixel`. That said, there's no point in locking the `Bitmap` if you're going to use `GetPixel` and `SetPixel` anyway - unless that's handled by the `LockBitmap` class (is that something you wrote?)

Comment: Not something i wrote. Was strange to me also the Get and Set pixel. I wanted to use LockBits to make it faster since Get and Set Pixel is slow.

Comment: Yeah, that second example is a bit closer - although you'll probably want to work with pointer arithmetics (all you need is `ptr++`) and 32-bit pixel format (for one, that's almost definitely the one you actually have, for another, it allows you to use `uint*` rather easily. This is especially handy for your case, where you can just compare the whole int to white at once, and copy it over otherwise.

Comment: I tested your code with the same bitmap I used for my test (see my latest edit in answer below), and it works fine. There are some issues in your code that would prevent it from working correctly for all bitmap scenarios, but it works correctly for the standard 32 bpp scenario for which it was written. If you are seeing incorrect results, it's because your bitmaps themselves don't conform to the requirements (i.e. have pixels which are non-white outside the area to which you want to crop).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have found a sample code snippet that uses `LockBits()`, but you are not sure how it works or how to modify it to suit your specific need. So I will try to answer from that perspective.

First, a wild guess (since you didn't include the implementation of the `LockBitmap` class you're using in the first example): the `LockBitmap` class is some kind of helper class that is supposed to encapsulate the work of calling `LockBits()` and using the result, including providing versions of `GetPixel()` and `SetPixel()` which are presumably much faster than calling those methods on a `Bitmap` object directly (i.e. access the buffer obtained by calling `LockBits()`).

If that's the case, then modifying the first example to suit your need is probably best:

```
public void Change(Bitmap bmp)
{
    Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(bmp.Width, bmp.Height, bmp.PixelFormat);

    LockBitmap source = new LockBitmap(bmp),
        target = new LockBitmap(newBitmap);
    source.LockBits();
    target.LockBits();

    Color white = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255);
    for (int y = 0; y < source.Height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < source.Width; x++)
        {
            Color old = source.GetPixel(x, y);

            if (old != white)
            {
                target.SetPixel(x, y, old);
            }
        }
    }
    source.UnlockBits();
    target.UnlockBits();
    newBitmap.Save("d:\\result.png");
}
```

In short: copy the current pixel value to a local variable, compare that value to the `white` color value, and if it is *not* the same, go ahead and copy the pixel value to the new bitmap.

Some variation on the second code example should work as well. The second code example does explicitly what is (I've assumed) encapsulated inside the `LockBitmap` class that the first code example uses. If for some reason, the first approach isn't suitable for your needs, you can follow the second example.

In that code example you provide, most of the method there is just handling the "grunt work" of locking the bitmap so that the raw data can be accessed, and then iterating through that raw data.

It computes the `oRow` and `nRow` array offsets (named for "old row" and "new row", I presume) based on the outer `y` loop, and then accesses individual pixel data by computing the offset within a given row based on the inner `x` loop.

Since you want to do essentially the same thing, but instead of converting the image to grayscale, you just want to selectively copy all non-white pixels to the new bitmap, you can (should be able to) simply modify the body of the inner `x` loop. For example:

```
byte red = oRow[x * pixelSize + 2],
    green = oRow[x * pixelSize + 1],
    blue = oRow[x * pixelSize];

if (red != 255 || green != 255 || blue != 255)
{
    nRow[x * pixelSize + 2] = red;
    nRow[x * pixelSize + 1] = green;
    nRow[x * pixelSize] = blue;
}
```

The above would entirely replace the body of the inner `x` loop.

One caveat: do note that when using the `LockBits()` approach, knowing the pixel format of the bitmap is crucial. The example you've shown assumes the bitmaps are in 24 bpp format. If your own bitmaps are in this format, then you don't need to change anything. But if they are in a different format, you'll need to adjust the code to suit that. For example, if your bitmap is in 32 bpp format, you need to pass the correct `PixelFormat` value to the `LockBits()` method calls, and then set `pixelSize` to `4` instead of `3` as the code does now.

**Edit:**

You've indicated that you would like to crop the new image so that it is the minimize size required to contain all of the non-white pixels. Here is a version of the first example above that should accomplish that:

```
public void Change(Bitmap bmp)
{
    LockBitmap source = new LockBitmap(bmp);
    source.LockBits();

    Color white = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255);
    int minX = int.MaxValue, maxX = int.MinValue,
        minY = int.MaxValue, maxY = int.MinValue;

    // Brute-force scan of the bitmap to find image boundary
    for (int y = 0; y < source.Height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < source.Width; x++)
        {
            if (source.GetPixel(x, y) != white)
            {
                if (x < minX) minX = x;
                if (x > maxX) maxX = x;
                if (y < minY) minY = y;
                if (y > maxY) maxY = y;
            }
        }
    }

    Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(maxX - minx + 1, maxY - minY + 1, bmp.PixelFormat);
    LockBitmap target = new LockBitmap(newBitmap);
    target.LockBits();

    for (int y = 0; y < target.Height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < target.Width; x++)
        {
            target.SetPixel(x, y, source.GetPixel(x + minX, y + minY));
        }
    }
    source.UnlockBits();
    target.UnlockBits();
    newBitmap.Save("d:\\result.png");
}
```

This example includes an initial scan of the original bitmap, after locking it, to find the minimum and maximum coordinate values for any non-white pixel. Having done that, it uses the results of that scan to determine the dimensions of the new bitmap. When copying the pixels, it restricts the `x` and `y` loops to the dimensions of the new bitmap, adjusting the `x` and `y` values to map from the location in the new bitmap to the given pixel's original location in the old one.

Note that since the initial scan determines where the non-white pixels are, there's no need to check again when actually copying the pixels.

There are more efficient ways to scan the bitmap than the above. This version simply looks at every single pixel in the original bitmap, keeping track of the min and max values for each coordinate. I'm guessing this will be fast enough for your purposes, but if you want something faster, you can change the scan so that it scans for each min and max in sequence:

1. Scan each row from `y` of 0 to determine the first row with a non-white pixel. This is the min `y` value.
2. Scan each row from `y` of `source.Height - 1` backwards, to find the max `y` value.
3. Having found the min and max `y` values, now scan the columns from `x` of 0 to find the min `x` and from `source.Width - 1` backwards to find the max `x`.

Doing it that way involves a lot more code and is probably harder to read and understand, but would involve inspecting many fewer pixels in most cases.

**Edit #2:**

Here is a sample of the output of the second code example:
[image: smile, original and cropped side-by-side]
Note that all of the white border of the original bitmap (shown on the left side) has been cropped out, leaving only the smallest subset of the original bitmap that can contain all of the non-white pixels (shown on the right side).

Comment: Peter in the first example in this line target.SetPixel(x, y, old); after it's setting all the non white colors to the new bitmap. How can i change the new bitmap size to be in the size of the non white colors ? Not to be in the size of the original bmp. But to be in the end in the size of the set pixels.

Comment: _"in the size of the set pixels"_ -- do you mean you want the new bitmap's actual size to be reduced, so that it is the smallest bitmap possible to contain only the non-white pixels? If so, then you will need to add code to scan the bitmap (e.g. before you actually copy it) to determine what the desired output boundary is (i.e. finding the min/max of the x and y values where a non-white pixel was found), and then use that information both to determine the output bitmap size and to offset the x/y coordinates when setting the output pixel (i.e. to eliminate white pixel areas to the left/top)

Comment: You right. Every image i want it to be reduced so it will contain only the non white pixels. So when i upload for example the image to facebook it wion't be with all the white around it. Seems not easy at all.

Comment: Peter i tried it now. Created a new class and added there this method: http://pastebin.com/357vKTyj then in form1 i did: Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(CropImageWhiteAreas.TrimBitmap(SaveImageFromWebBrowser(webBrowser1)));
                Change(bmp1); where the metho Change is your code. And SaveImageFromWebBrowser is just a method to capture the image in the webBrowser: http://pastebin.com/VnzumYDR

Comment: Peter but after using the new class i did with the new method here pastebin.com/357vKTyj the only thing changed is that now the white area i wanted to crop is black.

Comment: Please see my edit. Note that I did not have time to actually compile or test the code; you might find some typographical error in it, but I hope the example is useful to you.

Comment: I finally got some time to test the code I posted, and I've verified it works fine. Please note that this algorithm can only crop the bitmap correctly if there is _no_ non-white pixels outside the area to which you want to crop. I looked at the bitmap you'd posted earlier, and it has some almost-but-not-quite-white pixels along the right edge (for future reference, please do not edit your question so heavily...it's fine to _add_ things, but when you delete content that has already been referenced in comments or answers, you break all of the discussion so far).